# Angular Ng2SearchPipeModule

Tags: java, html, css, angular, pipe

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

IntelliJ is giving me the message " Class Ng2SearchPipeModule is not an Angular module ". Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check Ng2SearchPipeModule to have proper decorator. It has to be NgModule like your app module has.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class Ng2SearchPipeModule { }
```

Also, check if the import path is correct

Comment: It appears to be an `NgModule` indeed: https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/blob/master/src/ng2-filter.module.ts

Comment: Do you have some build-time errors (ng build or ng serve)?

Comment: Yes, The build error i get is: "Error: The target entry-point "ng2-search-filter" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/core"

Comment: Sometimes the following helps: delete node_modules than run 'npm i' and run build again

Comment: It kinda worked, accept now i got another error: "
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:8:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-search-filter' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 import {Ng2SearchPipeModule} from 'ng2-search-filter';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"